# Run multiple MySQL statements and log statements that generated error

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I'm migrating a CRM to another CRM system and I'm trying to run 5,000 insert statements in a table which creates relationships between 2 entities (Company > Employee)
However in the old CRM some companies/employees no longer exist yet the relationship is still there.

So when I try to import a relationship with one of the entities missing, I get an error.

I would like to run all 5,000 insert statements and keep a log of WHICH statements generated error.

Is there any way to do this? I'm using MySQL Workbench but I can do it in command line too if that is easier.

```
INSERT INTO `fb_civicrm`.`civicrm_relationship` (`contact_id_a`, `contact_id_b`, `relationship_type_id`, `is_active`, `description`, `is_permission_a_b`, `is_permission_b_a`) VALUES ((SELECT entity_id  FROM fb_civicrm.civicrm_value_sugar_info_1 WHERE sugarcrmid_1 = 'e03a03ae-13d1-4bdb-799f-4fe7f3801f65' AND entity_id > 13451), (SELECT entity_id  FROM fb_civicrm.civicrm_value_sugar_info_1 WHERE sugarcrmid_1 = '8ca77aa9-8bfc-2516-85ca-4fe7f2fa48bb' AND entity_id < 13452 ), '5', '1', '', '0', '0');
```

So A: I need some way to continue running my statements even if I get a subquery error (Ex: contact_id_a cannot be null)

and B: I need a way to filter the output in MySQL workbench to show only errors.

((Irrelevant to the question, but in case you wonder: The first ID is the id of the old system of the employee, and the second one is the ID of the company in the old system. I use the < 13451 because the old system had repeated IDs between employee and company (So a company could be ID 1, and a user could also be ID 1..both in the same table...) And in my import to the new system all companies are under ID 13451, and all employees are over that))

Answer (score 0):

It might not be the best solution, so I encourage other people to post others if they have any in mind, but I used:

IFNULL to run my sub-queries, which allows you to check if a certain value is null (in this case the result of my subquery) and if it is then replace the value with something else. Which for me was a dummy user which was connected to all broken relationships. Sample of my query:

```
INSERT INTO `fb_civicrm`.`civicrm_relationship` (`contact_id_a`, `contact_id_b`, `relationship_type_id`, `is_active`, `description`, `is_permission_a_b`, `is_permission_b_a`) VALUES ((SELECT IFNULL((SELECT entity_id  FROM fb_civicrm.civicrm_value_sugar_info_1 WHERE sugarcrmid_1 = 'a9a7ef90-f5c8-1f1d-b4c0-596c16ac363e' AND entity_id > 13451),'20459')), (SELECT IFNULL((SELECT entity_id  FROM fb_civicrm.civicrm_value_sugar_info_1 WHERE sugarcrmid_1 = '974' AND entity_id < 13452 ),'20459')), '5', '1', '', '0', '0');
```